# Is there any way to distinguish Characters and digits from string

Tags: java, android

I have one string contains characters and int I'm trying to store it separately, like-- all character in `List<String>` and all digits in `List<Integer>` any other proper way to do this without using NumberFormatException

My string is-

```
String s="asdjd7gd7fghdfg78895983745hkg98353j56li67hj595j595695g596496890";
```

Comment: Yes, you can use regex with `replaceAll()` or a loop and check ASCII value of each char

Comment: For future reference, a digit _is_ a character, so you really can't separate "characters" from "digits".  You can separate letters from digits, or nondigits from digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As TheLostMind said, you can utilize `replaceAll()` with some regex to separate digits and non-digit characters from that `String`:

```
String s="asdjd7gd7fghdfg78895983745hkg98353j56li67hj595j595695g596496890";
String digits = s.replaceAll("[a-z]", "");
String nonDigits = s.replaceAll("[0-9]", "");
```

From there, it's pretty trivial to store `digits` and `nonDigits` any way you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
String s = "asdjd7gd7fghdfg78895983745hkg98353j56li67hj595j595695g596496890";

List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Integer> in = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    String kek = String.valueOf(s.charAt(i));
    if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
        in.add(Integer.parseInt(kek));
    } else {
        str.add(kek);
    }
}
Log.e("String", str.toString());
Log.e("Integer", in.toString());
```

**Output :**

> String: [a, s, d, j, d, g, d, f, g, h, d, f, g, h, k, g, j, l, i, h,
> j, j, g]
>
> Integer: [7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 5, 9, 8, 3, 7, 4, 5, 9, 8, 3, 5,
> 3, 5, 6, 6, 7, 5, 9, 5, 5, 9, 5, 6, 9, 5, 5, 9, 6, 4, 9, 6, 8, 9, 0]